# Carpet for noise reduction (tests / studies)

Tags: architecture

Sorry if this is the wrong forum, I'm not an engineer but I'd need a pro to answer my question.

**Short version:**
Are there any tests or studies, if a carpet in an apartement can reduce noise from the apartment below. I'm searching for numbers rather than oppinions. The noise comes in all frequencies and shapes, from trampling to yelling, machine noise etc.

If there aren't any tests, please give me your oppinion, if you're an experienced professional in this field.

**Long version:**
I need to find a way to reduce noise in my apartment. I'm living in the topmost floor, so only the noise from below is the problem. Apparently our landlord put laminate in all apartements, without any form of insulation. My neighbors aren't the type of people that seem to be (neither could be made) aware, that noise exists.

After browsing the web for months, trying out various earplugs for >300$, hanging thick curtains, rearanging my apartement etc. I'm just searching for something more. If it's 5% less noise - fine. If it doesn't help at all I don't want to spend time and money on it. 
I know, that I propably should better find a new place to live or make my neighbors be more silent, but this is not a perfect world, things cannot be done in the best possible way.

Not sure why Mythbusters never tested this stuff.

EDIT:
[image: Soundproof bed]
**RED** = Insulation (Foam, ..., whatever)
**White** = Heavy wood
**Blue** = Inner shell, also heavy wood
What if I layed carpet and built something like this? I set up directional lamps for every wall and the ceiling. Sure, light is not sound, but it bounces too, right? Or will that totaly not work? Maybe I worsen it by that, like I build a trumpet..

Comment: soundproofing = mass + isolation

Comment: Can you explain that in detail (irl) for a noob like me?

Comment: Sounds are small vibrations of the air.  These vibrations are being transferred to the air in your room from the room below because the floor is vibrating.  You want the floor (and walls)  to vibrate less at all frequencies.  Because you can't isolate your floor (and walls) from your neighbour's room you have to make your floor (and walls) very heavy.  Other options include reflection and absorption while retaining structural strength. In a few years there will be products in the market for wall sound insulation that do not need much mass. Not so sure about floors.

Comment: There isn't a one-size-fits-all answer for sound isolation in apartment buildings.  As an example, I haven't heard much from my downstairs neighbors all summer. However, the heating was recently turned on in my building, and now I can hear them talking to each other (albeit muffled and indistinct).  My assumption is that the water filled heating pipes carry higher frequency sounds easily between the two apartments.

Comment: So for anyone with the same problem: I've built now the head part of the shell on the image, just an open box from heavy wood without any insulation yet. Inside I put a lot of pillows. This already reduced the noise in bed by estimated 5-10%, depending on the frequency. Along with a carpet + underlay, I will continue graduatly with this build, as it really works to some point. So even an open room-within-a-room does help some.

Comment: Another update on this: while the wooden shell improved the situation, the carpet didn't at all. So I could have saved myself the 250 bucks for the carpet, sadly. I will continue building with wood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a background in acoustics, noise control and vibrations. I haven't done much in the way of residential applications though.

Honestly, your best bet is to lay down heavy carpet with an underlayment designed to maximize sound absorption, like [this one](http://www.soundisolationcompany.com/solutions-products/soundproof-floors/carpet-floors/privacy-premium-carpet-underlay/). That doesn't mean that your problem will go away, or even be affected significantly.Since you're hearing sounds of all frequencies, in all likelihood there are "flanking paths" that allow sound from your downstairs neighbors into your apartment. These are typically things like ducts, pipes, walls and other vertical passages inherent in a multistory building.

The reason there aren't a lot of quantifiable measures and material ratings for sound reduction is that the testing required to give good results adds to the product cost. Most people are simply looking for a rug or carpet that will make their room look great. They aren't willing to pay a lot more for a material that's been tested. In any case, too much of a material's effectiveness in a given application depends on other factors that are beyond the control of the manufacturer. Just to give you an idea, consider what happens when sound waves hit a material surface. The energy from the sound can do three things. It can be reflected, it can be transmitted through or it can be absorbed by the material. What happens depends not just on the material, but also a great deal on the frequency of the sound, the angle of incidence and what's behind the material (i.e. the structure of the building).

It's entirely possible to design and construct buildings that minimize noise pollution between rooms/units, but for pre-existing structures, it can be all but impossible

Comment: I'd love to use that special stuff you linked, but as there's no price on it I expect it to be very expensive, is it? What exactly is that material, I tried to find it in Germany, but wasn't successful. What about 4mm cork below the carpet, would that be somewhat effective too?

Comment: I've never used it myself. Anything will be have some effect, but I'd look for a rubber based foam underlayment for sound damping.